Django,There is no module named "myapp"
enter image description here
PS C:\Users\taipe\firstproject> & C:/Users/taipe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/taipe/firstproject/firstproject/urls.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\taipe\firstproject\firstproject\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from myapp.views import sayhello,sayhello2,hello3      
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
PS C:\Users\taipe\firstproject>

enter image description here
I don`t know why there is the problem of "no module named "myapp" ".
however, there actually is a "myapp" folder in my "firstproject".

do you add myapp to your INSTALLED_APP on settings.py?

you didn't activate the virtual envrionment?

Have you been able to resolve this issue? If any of the answers helped you, please accept as answer. To accept as answer, click the tick mark next to the answer to toggle it from grey to green.

add ".." and try.
from ..myapp.views import {something}


A couple of fixes:

When you created your Django project, it came with a project level urls.py which can be found in your project directory. I can see this in your project. Ideally, you should use this to configure URLs for the admin and include your apps. You don't seem to have done that for myapp in this urls.py. It should look like this:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("myapp/", include("myapp.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]


As you created your app called myapp in your case, you should have an app level urls.py. Unlike the global urls.py, this is not automatically created for you. So create a file named urls.py in your app directory (where you have models.py, views.py, etc.) and map your URLs to your views (assuming you have sayhello, sayhello2, hello3 views in your views.py). Your app urls.py should look like this:

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", sayhello),
    path("sayhello2/<str:username>/", sayhello),
    path("hello3/<str:username>/", hello3),
]


Ensure you have added myapp to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # your app
    "myapp.apps.MyappConfig", # add this
    
    # default apps
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]


You don't seem to be using a virtual environment. Django strongly recommends that your projects be contained in a virtual environment with Django installed therein. See the docs for how to install Django properly.
I suggest you visit the official tutorial and follow the steps in creating your project, apps and other configurations.

